# How to arrange two blocks horizontally?

Tags: views, theming, blocks

I am going to create this, But I really don't know how to do it.

[image: news and health News]

**and I want to create one view with two blocks.**

what Format of view should be? (HTML list, Grid, Table, ...)

I don't know theming, How can I do this and arrange these blocks horizontally beside each other?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using [Panel](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module.

How can you use so I refer to [Link1](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-panels/) & [Link2](https://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-building-websites-using-panels-module?p=1137)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but the easiest is to use a view format of Grid, with 2 columns and alignment horizontal.
[Panel Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) , [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) or perhaps a [horizontal slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider)